# How can I set environment variables for a program executed using `nohup`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, nohup, subshell

(I'm editing an existing Bash script, so I'm probably making a silly mistake here...)

I have a shell script that saves a command with an environment variable as its argument like this:

```
COMMAND="mvn clean install -P $MAVEN_PROFILE"
```

It then executes the command with `nohup` roughly as follows:

```
nohup $COMMAND > logfile
```

This works.

Now, I want to set an environment variable that can be accessed in Maven. I've tried several things like the following:

```
COMMAND="FORMAVEN=valueForMaven mvn clean install -P $MAVEN_PROFILE"
```

...but then it just terminates with:

```
nohup: failed to run command `FORMAVEN=valueForMaven': No such file or directory
```

I feel like there are several unrelated concepts at work here, none of which I understand or even know about. What do I need to be able to do the above?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Three methods:

- set (and export) the variable before launching mvn
- set the variable on the nohup launch:

  ```
  FORMAVEN=valueForMaven nohup $COMMAND > logfile
  ```
- use env to set the variable

  ```
  COMMAND="env FORMAVEN=valueForMaven mvn clean install -P $MAVEN_PROFILE"
  ```

Comment: Excellent! I knew it had to be easier than the directions I was thinking of...

Comment: How come I never realised that it was as simple as export THEN run the command??? Thanks!